# I am trying to create a caption on a table, but got the error: captions outside float. I have written the code below,

Tags: captions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{green}{pink}
\caption{Timetable for on line class (F=法学；Y=营养)}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}

\caption{Timetable for on line class (F=法学；Y=营养)}
    & Mon  & Wed & Thurs & Fri \\
8：00-9:40am   & 法学1903  &  &法学1904 & 法学1901\\
    9:55-11:35am& 法学1902  &  &  & 营养1901  \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Either load the caption package and use capionof-command, or enclose your tabular in an table-environment.

Comment: `\caption{...}` cannot be inside `tabular` environment ...

Comment: @Zarko I updated my answer with you comments, since it make the answer more useful. However, I have credited you :=)

Comment: Off-topic, but please note that the CJK package is an outdated way to deal with Chinese input.  Please use XeLaTeX and change the first line to `\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}` instead.  Then, you can write 中文 without using any special environments.

Comment: You **can** put \caption inside a minipage or a p{} column, but you need to specify a width.

Answer (score 5):

Since you already load the caption package, use the command `\capionof{table}{The caption text}`, or enclose your tabular in an `table`-environment.

And, as @Zarko write in his comment, `\caption{...}` cannot be inside the `tabular`-environment (neither can `\captionof`).

I have corrected the spacing issue in the second row (8:00). Typographically, you should use `en`-space (`--` or `–`), not hyphen `-` to indicate the timespan:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{green}{pink}
\captionof{table}{Timetable for on line class (F=法学；Y=营养)}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}

    & Mon  & Wed & Thurs & Fri \\
8:00--9:40am   & 法学1903  &  &法学1904 & 法学1901\\ %% Corrected space
9:55--11:35am& 法学1902  &  &  & 营养1901  \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend deleting the second `\captionof` directive.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because, as the error message is telling you, there is a caption placed outside of a float environment. You could simply place the `tabular` environment inside of a `table` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}
\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{green}{pink}
\caption{Timetable for on line class (F=法学；Y=营养)}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
    & Mon  & Wed & Thurs & Fri \\
8：00-9:40am   & 法学1903  &  &法学1904 & 法学1901\\
    9:55-11:35am& 法学1902  &  &  & 营养1901  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]